# Polymorphic Query and Cartesian Product

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, persistence, cartesian-product

In the Hibernate User Guide, at [example "Example 182. Join Table polymorphic query"](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html) there is a note

> Polymorphic queries can create Cartesian Products, so caution is
>   advised.

Could someone explain how the Cartesian Products might happen in a such a use case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a correct statement. I created the [HHH-11175](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-11175) Jira issue, and I'm going to fix it.

I'm going to change that phrase to:

> The joined table inheritance polymorphic queries can use several JOINS
>   which might affect performance when fetching a large number of
>   entities.